# Making a subcomponent inherit depedencys from different components

Tags: dagger-2

Lately i've been working a lot with Dagger 2 and I'm having this particular use case that I'm not able to do the way I want to for different reasons:
1) It's not possible; 2) I'm just not understanding the concepts behind scopes and components/subcomponents.

I have 3 Components: AppComponent, DBComponent, ActivityComponent.

I need to have my activity to inherit dependencies from AppComponent and DBComponent. This is my following setup:

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class }) {
   EventBus bus()
   ActivityComponent plus(ActivityModule activityModule);
}
```

DatabaseComponent:

```
@Database
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = DatabaseModule.class) {
   ActivityDependency activityDependency();
}
```

ActivityComponent:

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = ActivityModule.class) {
   void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

When I inject bus() everything works fine but as soon as I try to inject ActivityDependency() it simply does not work. I cannot figure out why...

Please note: I've read about almost all the posts in here and outside explaining scopes, components and subcomponents and still I can't get my head wrapping around how to achieve what I wanted.

Note 2: I know one way to fix this which is to add DatabaseModule.class as a module in the AppComponent and remove DatabaseComponent from the equation. But I feel this will make AppComponent with too much information and this is not really the go to way.

Answer (score 1):

> inherit dependencies from AppComponent and DBComponent.

Wrong. You need to inherit dependencies from `AppComponent`, and the contents of the `DBComponent` should be a module of `AppComponent`.

> Note 2: I know one way to fix this which is to add DatabaseModule.class as a module in the AppComponent and remove DatabaseComponent from the equation. But I feel this will make AppComponent with too much information and this is not really the go to way.

Yes, it is the go-to way if you're using scoped dependencies.

---

Think of dependency **inheritance** like the `extends` keyword in Java.

You cannot extend multiple classes with the same class, can you?

Similarly, you cannot extend multiple scoped components either.

So if you want your graph to provide bindings for a given scope, then your component needs to have all the modules for that given scope. And `@Database` isn't really a scope (think lifecycles), that's a renamed `@Singleton`.

Comment: I've never thought about dependencies as extends and that makes perfect sense. And yeah scope as lifecycles also makes sense. And with that in mind for sure database would be a @singleton